# Seeding database for comments with two dependencies projects and users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to seed my database of comments but is not working as I'm not quite sure of how to do it

```
#Comments Creation
users = User.order(:created_at).take (6)
projects = Project.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
projects.each { |project| project.comments.create!(body: content , user_id: @user.id) }
end
```

The error I'm getting

```
rails db:seed
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Comments.model

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
```

routes

```
resources :projects do
resources :comments
end
```

Also db for comments

> id/body/user_id/project_id

Any ideas? Thanks :)

---- Solution ! ----

Thanks to Gaston

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take (6)
projects = Project.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
    users.each do |user|
        content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
        projects.each { |project| project.comments.create!(body: content, user_id: user.id) }
    end 
end
```

Comment: where is @user? the error is in this line I think projects.each { |project| project.comments.create!(body: content , user_id: @user.id) }

Comment: yes, i havent specified @user how can I do that? as I will be seeding the users too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take (6)
projects = Project.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
    users.each do |@user|
        content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
        projects.each { |project| project.comments.create!(body: content , user_id: @user.id) }
    end 
end
```

Here is an alternative

if for example you wanted only 60 in total per project

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take (6)
projects = Project.order(:created_at).take(6)

projects.each do |project| 
    10.times do 
        users.each do |@user|
            content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
            project.comments.create!(body: content , user_id: @user.id) }
        end 
    end 
end
```

finally, to seed users

```
  6.times do |n|
    name = Faker::Name.name
    email = "sasexample-#{n+1}@example.org"
    User.create!( 
                name: name, 
                email: email,
                password:   "exampleexample")
   end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but you almost got it right. I tweaked with it a bit and finally manage to get it, however it has been a team effort so I'll be granting your answer as good, gj! 

See the edit 1 for the resolution